# Convert CRS for spatial join for GeoDataFrame

Tags: spatial-join, geopandas

I have the following 2 GeoDataFrame variables in GeoPandas.

```
# shp.csr
{'init': 'epsg:2953'}

# line.csr
{'proj': 'sterea',
 'lat_0': 46.5,
 'lon_0': -66.5,
 'k': 0.999912,
 'x_0': 2500000,
 'y_0': 7500000,
 'ellps': 'GRS80',
 'towgs84': '0,0,0,0,0,0,0',
 'units': 'm',
 'no_defs': True}
```

When I do a `sjoin` of the 2 variables directly, a warning occurs:

```
/Users/jeff/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py:44: UserWarning: CRS of frames being joined does not match!
  warn('CRS of frames being joined does not match!')
```

How do I convert the CRS so that I can do a sjoin() correctly?

Comment: Reproject one of them http://geopandas.org/projections.html#re-projecting (i.e. `line.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:2953'})`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
line = line.to_crs(epsg=2953)
```

Comment: how fast is this method? With about 30k rows, it took about 20 minutes to finish. is that expected? thanks